# Арифметическая операция с c#

Tags: c#

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Console.Write("Введите имя первого игрока- ");
string one = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Введите имя второго игрока- ");
string two = Console.ReadLine();
int bet=1;
int sum,sum2;
do {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nПодход {bet}");
        Console.Write("Ход первого игрока- ");
        int a=rnd.Next(1,7);
        int b=rnd.Next(1,7);
        sum=a+b;
        Console.Write(sum);
        Console.Write("\nХод второго игрока- ");
        a=rnd.Next(1,7);
        b=rnd.Next(1,7);
        sum2=a+b;
        Console.Write(sum2);
        ++bet;
} while (bet < 4);

int go = sum+sum+sum;
int go1 = sum2+sum2+sum2;
if (go > go1) {
    Console.WriteLine($"\nВыиграл {one} со счетом {go}:{go1}");
} else if (go1 > go) {
    Console.WriteLine($"\nВыиграл {two} со счетом {go1}:{go}");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("\nНичья"); 
}
```

**Здравствуйте, только начал изучать c#. Как правильно написать чтобы не выводил арифметическую ошибку**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пытался не очень сильно переписывать Вашу программу. Исправив проблему и кое-что убрав, я получил такой код:

```cs
Random rnd = new Random ();
Console.Write ("Введите имя первого игрока- ");
string one = Console.ReadLine ();
Console.Write ("Введите имя второго игрока- ");
string two = Console.ReadLine ();
int bet = 1;
int sum = 0, sum2 = 0;
do {
    Console.WriteLine ($"\nПодход {bet}");
    Console.Write ("Ход первого игрока- ");
    int a = rnd.Next (2, 13);
    sum += a;
    Console.Write (a);
    Console.Write ("\nХод второго игрока- ");
    int b = rnd.Next (2, 13);
    sum2 += b;
    Console.Write (b);
    ++bet;
} while (bet < 4);
if (sum > sum2)
    Console.WriteLine ($"\nВыиграл {one} со счетом {sum}:{sum2}");
else if (sum2 > sum)
    Console.WriteLine ($"\nВыиграл {two} со счетом {sum2}:{sum}");
else
    Console.WriteLine ("\nНичья");
```

1. У Вас в sum записывается сума двух рандомных чисел. Я заменил это на получение одного рандомного числа, так как смысла в двух нет;
2. В конце Вы суммируете 3 раза sum, но у Вас остаётся только последнее значение этой переменной, а именно последний ход первого игрока (тоже самое у второго). Таким образом Вы просто умножаете последние результаты на 3 (6*3=18 и 5*3=15), вместо суммирования всех предыдущих результатов. Я заменил go на sum и в него добавляю результаты каждого раунда. Проблема решена.